# Shell Help to replace double quotes

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Need help to replace double quotes to the escape charchter, please find the below one line code:

```
echo -e "nzsql -d $f1 -c" \"alter table $f3.$f2 ALTER COLUMN $f4 SET DEFAULT $v5\"
```

The output is:

```
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN CD_ID SET DEFAULT '-9999' "
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN LMT_ID SET DEFAULT 99' "
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN PPN_TM SET DEFAULT "TIMESTAMP"('now(0)'::"VARCHAR") "
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN SRC_STM_ID SET DEFAULT '-9999' "
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN UNQ_ID_IN_SRC_STM SET DEFAULT 'MISSING_VALUE'::"NVARCHAR" "
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN END_DT SET DEFAULT '9999/12/31' "
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN EFF_DT SET DEFAULT '1900/01/01' "
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN ISRT_RUN_ID SET DEFAULT '-9999' "
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN UDT_RUN_ID SET DEFAULT '-9999' "
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN UDT_RUN_ID SET DEFAULT -9999 "
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN UDT_RUN_ID SET DEFAULT 9999 "
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN UDT_RUN_ID SET DEFAULT Now() "
nzsql -d  DD  -c "alter table SCHEMA.DD ALTER COLUMN LAST_VRSN_F SET DEFAULT '1' "
```

I am using above command to prepare alter table statements

The below are V5 values

```
'-9999'
'-9999'
"TIMESTAMP"('now(0)'::"VARCHAR")
'-9999'
'MISSING_VALUE'::"NVARCHAR"
'9999/12/31'
'1900/01/01'
'-9999'
'-9999'
9999
Now()
now(0)
'1'
```

What I just need to do is if the v5 values has `"` then just replace that with `\"` and the rest if it has single quotes or no quotes must just remain the same.

I tried

```
v5=`sed $v5/"/\"`
```

and

```
v5=`echo ${v5/"/\"/}`
```

Did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
v5="$(echo "$v5" | sed 's/"/\\"/g')"

# this is your original command without any changes
echo -e "nzsql -d $f1 -c" \"alter table $f3.$f2 ALTER COLUMN $f4 SET DEFAULT $v5\"
```

Explanation:

- `echo "$v5" | sed`: sed reads the $v5 from STDIN;
- `'s/"/\\"/`: substitute `"` with `\"` but only for the first occurrence of `"` in the line;
- `g`: apply the substitution for every occurrence of `"` in the line.

---

If you use `bash4` or above, you can omit `echo`:

```sh
v5="$(sed 's/"/\\"/g' <<<"$v5")"
```

---

As you mentioned in the end of your question, you can omit `sed` and use native `bash`'s substitution:

```sh
VAR="${VAR//\"/\\\"}"
```